# Creating JSON with dynamic fields without using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I have a working JavaScript code below which dynamically creates JSON object using JSON.parse method. Is there a shorter way to do this?

```
var a = '"hi"'; 
var obj = '{' + a + ':' + '"abc"' + '}';
console.log(JSON.parse(obj)); // outputs: OBJECT: {"hi":"abc"}
```

something simplier like...

```
var a='hi';
console.log({a:"abc"}); // but outputs: OBJECT: {a:"abc"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use square brackets to access a property whose name you have as a string:

```
var a = "hi";
var obj = {}; //obj is an object literal
obj[a] = "abc"; //Set the 'hi' property of obj
```

Note that JSON is just a data format. It is not JavaScript. You want a JavaScript object literal, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create a JSON string by creating a regular JavaScript object, and using `JSON.stringify`

Example:

```
var obj = { "hi": "abc" };
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

// Output '{"hi":"abc"}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But the one above is what I'm looking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var obj = {};
obj["hi"] = "abc";
```

or

```
var obj = {};
obj.hi = "abc";
```

and then console.log(obj);